# What is the ground state of a Hamiltonian in $k$-space after Bogoliubov transformation?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory, condensed-matter, hamiltonian, second-quantization

Consider the following Hamiltonian in $k$-space, quadratic in terms of the $\gamma$ operators:
\begin{equation}
    \hat{H}_2=\frac{1}{2}\sum_k 
    \begin{pmatrix}
    \gamma_k^\dagger & \gamma_{-k}
    \end{pmatrix}
    \begin{pmatrix}
    A_k & B_k \\
    B_k^* & A_k^*
    \end{pmatrix}
    \begin{pmatrix}
    \gamma_k \\
    \gamma_{-k}^\dagger
    \end{pmatrix}
    + \text{cte},
\end{equation}
where $\gamma_{k}=(\gamma_{k,1},\gamma_{k,2},...,\gamma_{k,n_{max}})^T$ is a vector operator.

A Bogoliubov transformation is performed
\begin{equation}
    \begin{pmatrix}
        \gamma_k\\
        \gamma^\dagger_{-k}
    \end{pmatrix}=T_k
    \begin{pmatrix}
                \lambda_k\\
        \lambda^\dagger_{-k}
    \end{pmatrix},
\end{equation}
and
\begin{equation}
T_k^{\dagger}   \begin{pmatrix}
    A_k & B_k \\
    B_k^* & A_k^*
    \end{pmatrix}T_k=\begin{pmatrix}
    \omega_{k} & 0 \\
    0 & \omega_{k}
    \end{pmatrix},
\end{equation}
where $\omega_{k}=\operatorname{diag}(\omega_{k,1},...,\omega_{k,n_{max}})$,
so that the Hamiltonian is diagonalized, and now is given by:
\begin{equation}
\hat{H}_2=\sum_{k} \sum_{\alpha=1}^{n_{max}} \omega_{k,\alpha}\hat{\lambda}_{k,\alpha}^{\dagger}\hat{\lambda}_{k,\alpha}.
\end{equation}

Now, what would the ground state $|\psi_0\rangle$ be?
I cannot understand, for example, how could I calculate the expectation value $\langle\gamma_{}i^{\dagger}\gamma_j \rangle$ in terms of the matrices.

Comment: What does "cte" mean?